# Create dictionary from one column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to create a dictionary from a single pandas dataframe column in which the value and key are the same? Sounds crazy but its the only way I can think to solve a problem I am having.

given the following df:

```
Color
 red

dict1 = { 'red' : 'red' } 

dict1 = df.reset_index().set_index(['color'])['color'].to_dict()
```

Comment: what does that pandas dataframe look like??? it the column `red` and one of its values is `red`??

Comment: @MattR the dataframe would look how it is in the question. One column for color.

Comment: just curious, why would you want a dict with same keys and values? Wouldn't a set be enough then?

Comment: "Sounds crazy but its the only way I can think to solve a problem I am having." THIS IS A CLASSIC SYMPTOM OF THE [XY PROBLEM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain your actual problem if it applies to pandas because there is likely to be a 10x better solution.

Comment: sounds like you need dict(zip())

Comment: Nice one, bookmarked that, ready to use it on lot of questions :) @cs95

Comment: @MaxB, you only gave us an unformatted dataframe. are their more values possible in the color? You probably need to add more detail with an expected output.

Comment: `{x:x for x in df['Color']}` ..?

Comment: `dict(zip(*[df.color] * 2))` or this for goofs (don't actually do this) `{**pd.Index(df['color']).to_series()}`

Comment: @cs95 what makes it so absurd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
dict1 = {}

for i in df['Color']:
    dict1[i] = i
```

Comment: Thank you:) this accomplishes what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: I am glad I could help. If this answers your question, please accept it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
dict1 = dict(zip(df['Color'], df['Color']))
```